# CMAKE TASKING TOOLSET Usage

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

I am quite new to cmake. Cmake had recently added support for TASKING Tool Set

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TASKING_TOOLSET.html

While searching on Github, I found the following information:

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/Tasking-C.cmake

Unfortunately, I am unable to understand this. Can you please help me to write a CMakeLists.txt file to configure the TASKING tool set in cmake?

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/Tasking-C.cmake

I don't know how to use this file.

Comment: If none of the keywords mentioned in the cmake documentation is familiar to you, you probably don't need to set this variable. If you check [the changelog](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.25.html?highlight=cmake_tasking_toolset#compilers) though it mentions the added `Tasking` [compiler id](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html) which contains this link for the compiler: https://www.tasking.com/ Are you using a compiler of this company? If not, the variable shouldn't be relevant to you.

Comment: Btw: the variable documentation refers to [cmake toolchain files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) so you shouldn't be setting it inside your `CMakeLists.txt` or directly via command line variable, but by providing the name of a cmake script file via `--toolchain ...` command line option during the `cmake` configuration step.

Comment: Thank Fabian, Yes i am using the compiler of TASKING. I would highly appreciate if you can direct me to an example for --toolchain ... which is expecting a cmake script file.